# Bootstrap layout breaking wrong when inserting space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

All that I need is put padding or margin between columns.

If I set it in css, the columns break down.

The code html and css is here:

https://codeshare.io/2pwRPz

Without margin, 3 columns, ok but without space:

[image: Without margin, 3 columns, ok]

With css margin, not ok:

[image: With css margin, with space but not ok]

My css, uncomment this css to see the problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is breaking to the next line because of the margin left you are applying - to get the desired space - what you need to do is to insert the cards WITHIN the col-md-4, and put padding to the div so that the cards will have space between them, but remain within the bootstrap layout.

```
//css 
.cards-postagens-wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
}

.cards-postagens {
    background-color: #d4ecd6;
    height: 9em;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }

//html
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 cards-postagens-wrapper">
      <div class="cards-postagens">
        <div class="badge badge-primary badge-postagens">categoria blog</div>
         <div>12 a column here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is demoonstrated by the following snippet.

```css
.cards-postagens-wrapper  {
  padding: 15px;
 }
 
.cards-postagens {
    background-color: #d4ecd6;
    height: 9em;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.badge-postagens {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="container" id="corpo-pagina">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="corpo-pagina-conteudo">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cards-postagens-wrapper">
      <div class="cards-postagens">
        <div class="badge badge-primary badge-postagens">
            categoria blog
         </div>
         <div>11 a column here</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cards-postagens-wrapper">
      <div class="cards-postagens">
        <div class="badge badge-primary badge-postagens">
            categoria blog
         </div>
         <div>11 a column here</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cards-postagens-wrapper">
      <div class="cards-postagens">
        <div class="badge badge-primary badge-postagens">
            categoria blog
         </div>
         <div>11 a column here</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @gavgrif, your code worked very well for me, and your explanation is excellent!